# has_and_belongs_to external database join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

This may be a case where I need to use has_many :through, but I'd prefer not to as this is a simple join table without attributes case.

My provider table is in an external database:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :external_db
  set_table_name :ch_cdn
  set_primary_key :cdn_id

  has_and_belongs_to_many :dashboards
end

Class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :providers
end
```

But when I try: 
    Dashboard.first.providers << Provider.first

I get

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table
>   'chshared.dashboards_providers' doesn't exist: SELECT `ch_cdn`.* FROM
>   `ch_cdn` INNER JOIN `dashboards_providers` ON `ch_cdn`.`cdn_id` =
>   `dashboards_providers`.`provider_id` WHERE
>   `dashboards_providers`.`dashboard_id` = 1

It's looking in the wrong database for the join table.  Is it possible to specify that 'dashboards' providers lives in the other database?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a typo, but look at "Class Dashboard", should be "class Dashboard".  Plus this is back from Nov. so I think you already solved it.

Comment: Never solved it, ended up moving the table to the shared database.